# Поправка кода javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте есть такой код.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function getText(el){
  document.getElementById('zubn').value += ', ' + el.firstChild.data;
  }
 </script>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="14">Какойто текст1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getText(this)" id="15">Какойто текст2</a></li>
```

Как Вы уже заметили при нажатии на ссылку он вставляет значение ссылки в поле с айдишником zubn (т е он заполняет это поле при нажатии) через запятую. Код работает отлично , но есть одно НО, он и в начале строки тоже ставит запятую. Как сделать так чтоб первое значение он ставил без запятой , но а потом если есть другие значения то он их разделял запятыми

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('zubn').value += (document.getElementById('zubn').value ? ', ' : '') + el.firstChild.data;`

Comment: БИНГОО !!! Евгений Миронов, от души благодарен Вам за помощь !!!

Comment: А может лучше не делать каждый раз в цикле проверку, а просто сконкатенировать всё, а потом сделать `ltrim()` для нужных символов? или такого нет в js?

Comment: На js вообще ноль к сожалению ( , но будем ждать ответа от знатоков этой сферы )

Comment: Есть, можно и удалить просто первые 2 символа. `document.getElementById('zubn').substr(2)`

Но если оптимизировать, то для начала надо `document.getElementById('zubn')` записать в переменную =)

Answer (score 1):

Путь регулярных:

```js
var str = ",test, yoyoyoy, hello,"
//str = str.replace(/(^, )|(, $)/g, "") <--- для запятой с пробелом
str = str.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, ""); 
console.log(str);
```

То есть можно всё также в цикле сконкатенировать, а затем в конце обрезать ненужное.